# How to convert crystal report into jasper report?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I want to generate jasper report for available crystal report. I am trying to find a way by which I can convert available .rpt files into jasper jrxml files. But I didn't find any such way? Is it really possible with any tool?

Even I read that Crystal Report is not open source so developing any tool which convert crystal reports to jasper reports is against the law? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it is possible to convert Crystal Report to Jasper Report. But Crystal Report is licensed and Jasper Community is free so there is not any tool provided by and vendor for this type of conversion.

However, a tool can be developed for this conversion.